# php-fpm /status file not found

Tags: php, nginx

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.2 **Webserver:** Nginx 1.18.0 **PHP:** 8.0.5

---

I wanted to activate the `/status` page for PHP-FPM and tried the following:

- In `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/`, I added the line `pm.status_path = /status` to the pool file of the site I want to monitor.
- In the Nginx server block of the site, I added the following:

```
    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
      access_log off;

      # allow 127.0.0.1;
      # allow 1.2.3.4;
      # deny all;

      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      ## Now the port or socket of the php-fpm pool we want the status of
      fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
      # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/your_socket.sock;
    }
```

- Reloaded and restarted php8.0-fpm and nginx

But when I try to access https://example.com/status (example.com is representational) or curl the URL, I get a "file not found" message.

How do I activate and display the `/status` page?

---

**N.B.** Test server so I commented out `allow` and `deny`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work after directly linking `fastcgi_param` to the `status.html` file by changing the following line:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

To this:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/php/8.0/fpm/status.html;
```

And the status page is finally working now.

Not really sure why `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` doesn't resolve to the relevant path though.